# send data from my activy class, to fragment class (tabs)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an activity class with a listview. If I click on an item of the listview, i want to go to my fragmentactivity class and pass some information in a bundle.

This is the code in my Activity class(ProviderList) with te listview.
EditSms is a fragment class (a tab).
EditBundle is the fragmentActivity class where the tabs are created.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

     EditSms fragment = new EditSms();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("position", position);
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     Intent i = new Intent(ProviderList.this, EditBundle.class);

    startActivity(i);

}
```

In my fragment class EditText i have following code:

```
public class EditSms extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
private Button bChangeSMS;
private EditText etSmsEN;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View editsms = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_frag, container, false);
     int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
     Log.d("test", "position: " + position);
    bChangeSMS = (Button)editsms.findViewById(R.id.bAdjustSMS);
    etSmsEN = (EditText)editsms.findViewById(R.id.etSmsEN);
    bChangeSMS.setOnClickListener(this);

    return editsms;
}
```

EditBundle:

```
    package com.example.mobieleplatformen;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;

public class EditBundle extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.editbundle);
        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
        Log.d("test", position + "");

        Bundle in = getIntent().getExtras();
        EditSms fragment = new EditSms();
        fragment.setArguments(in);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, fragment).commit();

        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        // Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                    FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        // Add New Tab
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Call")
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("SMS")
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Data")
                .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

EditSms:

```
package com.example.mobieleplatformen;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditSms extends Fragment implements
        OnClickListener {
    private Button bChangeSMS;
    private EditText etSmsEN;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View editsms = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_frag, container, false);

    int position = getArguments().getInt("position", 0);
    Log.d("test", "position: ");
    bChangeSMS = (Button) editsms.findViewById(R.id.bAdjustSMS);
    etSmsEN = (EditText) editsms.findViewById(R.id.etSmsEN);
    bChangeSMS.setOnClickListener(this);

    return editsms;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Logcat:

Logcat:
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.example.mobieleplatformen.EditSms.onCreateView(EditSms.java:25)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-21 19:49:51.541: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

When I run this code, i get a nullpointer exception. Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE?

Comment: getArguments() returns null

Comment: try changing fragment.setArguments(args); to fragment.putExtras(args); and  getArguments().getInt("position"); to getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

Comment: I didn't look at it right, sorry. Let me take a look and see if I can't figure it out

Comment: Oh, yes I got it. You need to pass the bundle to your FragmentActivity (EditBundle) where you get it with getIntent().getExtras().... like I thought above. Then you need to set your arguments for your fragment in EditBundle and get them in your fragment like you are.

Comment: Please post your complete EditBundle and EditSms class files, and you can remove the xml. Your errors aren't in there but thank you :)

Comment: Check my edit.. Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain about this and may need to edit some things after I get a change to try them, but I think that you need to do something like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);

    Intent i = new Intent(ProviderList.this, EditBundle.class);
    i.putExtras(args);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Then in your EditBundle's onCreate

```
Bundle in = getIntent().getExtras();
EditSms fragment = new EditSms();
fragment.setArguments(in);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

And then, if you haven't yet added your fragment

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

if not

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

And in EditSms, which must extend Fragment from your support library (import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;) because your FragmentActivity is from the support library, you can access after your activity is created

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    getArguments().getInt("positon", 0);
    //do whatever
}
```

That way you are passing your bundle through your intent, you are getting it in the activity that is started through your intent, and then you are setting the arguments of your fragment from it's containing Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it stil won't work. In EditBundle, I receive the position correctly, but if i want to pass it to EditSms, I still get de nullpointer...

Comment: @user3557718 check my edit. I think the problem is that you never actually add your fragment to the stack once you have set the arguments, so the arguments are still set to default.

Comment: I get an error with replace: "Change type of 'fragment' to Fragment". Have I done something else wrong then?

Comment: No, I am making stupid mistakes because I'm trying to do this from my cell. Give me a minute

Comment: @user3557718 check my edited answer and give it a shot.

Comment: Still getting this error: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, EditSms)

Comment: @user3557718 and EditSms extends Fragment?

Comment: Yes it does! I added my xml for my EditSms and EditBundle class in my question. Maybe i've done something wrong there?

Comment: @user3557718 got it. Remove your import for your Fragment in EditSms and import the Fragment from the support library. Check my edit

Comment: @user3557718 be sure to read through it carefully, the edits aren't very noticeable. You need to correct your import and change getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: I think you ment the import in EditBundle? Because in EditSms, i already have this import: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

But I did it in EditBundle, and still nullpointer :(

Comment: @user3557718 Did you modify to getSupportFragmentManager(); Can you post your LogCat?

Comment: @user3557718 and the nullpointer is at the getArguments line?

Comment: Yep, i think so. If i delete that line, everything runs fine

Comment: @user3557718 check my edit, move the call to onActivityCreated()

Comment: nope, that doesn't do the trick. I tried it in onActivityCreated() and in onViewCreated.

Comment: @user3557718 I may have been wrong about the xml. You don't add your fragment in xml do you? If so, try commenting it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a solution, and I think I found one. Maybe it's not the best, but it's good for now I think.

Activity class:

```
Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putInt("position", position);

         Intent i = new Intent(ProviderList.this, EditBundle.class);
        i.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(i);
```

EditBundle

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();

        position = gotBasket.getInt("position");
```

And i also make a getter for position.

```
public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
```

In my Fragment class, EditSms, i call the getter and get the position

```
EditBundle b = (EditBundle)getActivity();
        Log.d("pos", b.getPosition() + "");
```